# Socket null - Android Tcp socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I want to build a sample android app to make a socket based connection between another pc and my android application over TCP. This is my code of Client.java file for that:-

```
package com.myApp.android.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = ****;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "***.**.**.**";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("button click0", "happening");
        RequestLogin("userid", "password", "123456");

        /*try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

    class TMessageHeader {
        public short MessageCode;
        public int MessageLength;
        public byte ChannelId;
        public char[] ClientId = new char[16];
        public int TimeStamp;
        public int ErrorCode;
        public int ErrorMessageLength;
        public byte NumberOfDecimals;
        public char Source;
        public int ClientDispatcherID;
    }
    public TMessageHeader GetMessageHeader(String UserId, TLoginRequest pStructure) {
        Log.d("MessageHeader", "called");
        TMessageHeader msgHeader = new TMessageHeader();
        msgHeader.ChannelId = 0;//Need to be set on the bases of user Scrip Selection for cash ==> 0 and for FnO not yet decided.
        if (!UserId.isEmpty())
            msgHeader.ClientId = UserId.toCharArray();
        msgHeader.ErrorCode = 0;
        msgHeader.ErrorMessageLength = 0;
        msgHeader.MessageCode = 1;
        msgHeader.MessageLength = 134;
        msgHeader.NumberOfDecimals = 0;
        msgHeader.Source = 'A';
        msgHeader.TimeStamp = 0;
        Log.d("Returned", String.valueOf(msgHeader));
        return msgHeader;
    }

    class TLoginRequest {
        TMessageHeader messageHeader;
        char[] UserId = new char[20];
        char[] Password = new char[16];
        char[] IPAddress = new char[16];
        char[] MacAddress = new char[20];
        int VersionNo;
        char[] PanOrDOB = new char[13];
    }


    public void RequestLogin(String pLoginId, String pPassword, String pPanDOB) {
        Log.d("RequestLogin", "Called");
        TLoginRequest request = new TLoginRequest();
        request.IPAddress = "IPAddress".toCharArray();
        request.MacAddress = "MacAddress".toCharArray();
        request.PanOrDOB = pPanDOB.trim().toCharArray();
        request.Password = pPassword.trim().toCharArray();
        request.UserId = pLoginId.trim().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        request.VersionNo = Integer.parseInt("5");
        request.UserId = "userid".toCharArray();
        request.messageHeader = GetMessageHeader("userid", request);
        request.messageHeader.ClientId = pLoginId.trim().toCharArray();
        try {
            if(socket != null) {
                Log.d("Socket is not", "null");
            Log.d("OutputStream", String.valueOf(socket.getOutputStream()));
                OutputStreamWriter outwrite = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter buffwrite = new BufferedWriter(outwrite);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(buffwrite, true);
                out.println(request);
            }
            Log.d("Socket is", "null");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("IOException", "Occured");
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                Log.d("UnknownHostException", "true");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("IOException", "true");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

When i run this code,in log i get Socket is equals to null. How can i resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Log File :-

```
    03-17 11:57:46.227: D/AndroidRuntime(293): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    03-17 11:57:46.227: D/AndroidRuntime(293): CheckJNI is ON
    03-17 11:57:46.577: D/AndroidRuntime(293): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    03-17 11:57:46.597: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=301 uid=10003 gids={1015, 2001}
    03-17 11:57:46.798: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_EXPLICIT freed 292K, 54% free 2568K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 41ms
    03-17 11:57:46.957: W/ActivityManager(61): No content provider found for: 
    03-17 11:57:47.007: W/ActivityManager(61): No content provider found for: 
    03-17 11:57:47.018: D/PackageParser(61): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-912569523.tmp
    03-17 11:57:47.157: I/PackageManager(61): Removing non-system package:com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient
    03-17 11:57:47.157: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient uid=10041
    03-17 11:57:47.168: I/dalvikvm(61): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
    03-17 11:57:47.248: D/PackageManager(61): Scanning package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient
    03-17 11:57:47.248: I/PackageManager(61): Package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient codePath changed from /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-2.apk to /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
    03-17 11:57:47.248: I/PackageManager(61): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk
    03-17 11:57:47.258: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk' ---
    03-17 11:57:47.908: D/dalvikvm(312): DexOpt: load 78ms, verify+opt 352ms
    03-17 11:57:47.937: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk' (success) ---
    03-17 11:57:47.937: W/PackageManager(61): Code path for pkg : com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient changing from /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-2.apk to /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk
    03-17 11:57:47.948: W/PackageManager(61): Resource path for pkg : com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient changing from /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-2.apk to /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk
    03-17 11:57:47.948: D/PackageManager(61):   Activities: com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient.Client
    03-17 11:57:47.958: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient uid=10041
    03-17 11:57:48.078: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk@classes.dex
    03-17 11:57:48.078: D/PackageManager(61): New package installed in /data/app/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-1.apk
    03-17 11:57:48.186: I/ActivityManager(61): Force stopping package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient uid=10041
    03-17 11:57:48.238: D/dalvikvm(130): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 51% free 2906K/5895K, external 4767K/5643K, paused 49ms
    03-17 11:57:48.318: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=313 uid=10009 gids={}
    03-17 11:57:48.338: W/RecognitionManagerService(61): no available voice recognition services found
    03-17 11:57:48.528: I/ActivityThread(313): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
    03-17 11:57:48.588: D/dalvikvm(170): GC_EXPLICIT freed 294K, 52% free 2771K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 342ms
    03-17 11:57:48.658: D/dalvikvm(61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1092K, 47% free 4277K/8007K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 75ms
    03-17 11:57:48.738: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient-2.apk@classes.dex
    03-17 11:57:48.748: D/AndroidRuntime(293): Shutting down VM
    03-17 11:57:48.758: D/dalvikvm(293): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 72% free 295K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+1ms
    03-17 11:57:48.758: D/jdwp(293): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
    03-17 11:57:48.758: D/dalvikvm(293): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    03-17 11:57:49.088: D/AndroidRuntime(326): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    03-17 11:57:49.088: D/AndroidRuntime(326): CheckJNI is ON
    03-17 11:57:49.438: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    03-17 11:57:49.448: I/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient/.Client } from pid 326
    03-17 11:57:49.468: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient for activity com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient/.Client: pid=334 uid=10041 gids={3003}
    03-17 11:57:49.488: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Shutting down VM
    03-17 11:57:49.498: D/dalvikvm(326): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
    03-17 11:57:49.498: D/dalvikvm(326): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    03-17 11:57:50.178: I/ARMAssembler(61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x44c766f0:0x44c768a8] in 366685 ns
    03-17 11:57:50.468: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient/.Client: +1s9ms
    03-17 11:57:55.568: D/dalvikvm(130): GC_EXPLICIT freed 128K, 51% free 2890K/5895K, external 4816K/5643K, paused 55ms
    03-17 11:57:55.808: D/button click0(334): happening
    03-17 11:57:55.808: D/RequestLogin(334): Called
    03-17 11:57:55.808: D/MessageHeader(334): called
    03-17 11:57:55.808: D/Returned(334): com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient.Client$TMessageHeader@405345f8
    03-17 11:57:55.808: D/Socket is not(334): null
    03-17 11:57:55.818: D/OutputStream(334): org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream@40534ac8
    03-17 11:57:55.818: D/Socket is(334): null
03-17 12:01:49.917: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Is there any Exception Logs

Answer (score 1):

You get `Socket is(334): null` because you're printing it unconditionally. You're missing an `else.`